# django url patterns, how to match two different patterns with multiple options?

Tags: django, url

I have two patterns like this...

```
url(r'^(?P<page_lang>\w+)/(?P<page_title>\w+)/$', 'main.views.page', name='page_title'),
url(r'^(?P<foo>\w+)/choice/$', 'main.views.lang_pair_choice', name='lang_pair_choice'), 
url(r'^(?P<bar>\w+)/choice2/', include('quiz.urls')),
```

The problem is that when I pass 2 things into the URL /something/somethingelse it matches the first one and I am not sure how to get it to do something else

Answer (score 2, accepted):

reorder your urls like:

```
url(r'^(?P<foo>\w+)/choice/$', 'main.views.lang_pair_choice', name='lang_pair_choice'), 
url(r'^(?P<bar>\w+)/choice2/', include('quiz.urls')),
url(r'^(?P<page_lang>\w+)/(?P<page_title>\w+)/$', 'main.views.page', name='page_title'),
```

Learn more on how Django processes a request [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/http/urls/#how-django-processes-a-request)

Comment: neat solution, I will do that this time. In the future if I run across this again, is there any other way to accomplish this?

Comment: @deltaskelta Django runs through each URL pattern, in order, and stops at the first one that matches the requested URL. So in the future order your urls based on your requirement. Please check the link provided in my answer for more details

Comment: @deltaskelta you just need to make sure you  place the more general ones after the more specific ones. If you look at the regexes in this answer, the third one is able to match the first two, so you need to place it after.

Comment: Oh yes, I completely understand that part, what I was getting at is asking if ordering is the only way to do it, or if there was some other way if push came to shove. Thanks for the answer

Comment: @deltaskelta another way would be to add something before `^(?P<foo>\w+)/choice/$` like `^choices/(?P<foo>\w+)/choice/$` or `^choices/(?P<bar>\w+)/choice2/`, this way django will not match the first url and move to check the next one.